# How to find the ID of the next li (list item) within an ul (unordered list)

Tags: jquery

I'd like to pass a function the id of an `<LI>` and have it return the id of the next one available within the `<UL>`.

The id's may not be in order, and there are other elements nested within the `<LI>` so I can't just get the next one of those.

I've searched all over the web and tried various combinations without success.

HTML:

```
<ul class="timeline" id="timeline">

    <li id="timelineLI-1A4">
        <div class="timelineIcon letter"></div>
        <div class="dateContainer"></div>
    </li>

    <li id="timelineLI-2">
        <div class="timelineIcon mail"></div>
        <div class="dateContainer"></div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

JavaScript/JQuery Code:

```
function openNextTile() {
    console.log(lastTileOpened);

    // Get the current tile that's open
    if (lastTileOpened == null) {
        openFirstTile();
    } else {
        console.log('opening next tile with keyboard');
        var getNextLIID = $('ul#' + 'timelineTile-' + lastTileOpened).next();
        animateTile(getNextLIID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try [searching the API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/?s=next)?

Comment: provide your code and what you have tried

Comment: you can share your failed code.

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/328275

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems very easy to accomplish:

```
function getNext(id) {
    return $("#" + id).next("li").attr("id");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QKRrM/

Comment: Thanks - but that returns me 'undefined'?

Comment: So it does, I copy and pasted your code so I must be doing something wrong - I'll check first thing in the morning once I'm back at work.

Comment: @MichaelBellamy -- No problem. If you're actually passing the jQuery object into the function, then you'll have to tweak the function (replace `$("#" + id)` with whatever param you pass in)

Answer (score 0):

```
var nextId = function( id ) {
    return $('#' + id).next().attr('id');
};
```

Example usage:

```
<ul>
    <li id="one">...</li>
    <li id="two">...</li>
</ul>

console.log(nextId('one')); // "two"
```